# Does anybody recognize these wings?

Tags: wing, aircraft-identification

I was on a tour at the University of Maryland, and I saw these wings sitting against the wall:
[image]

I asked the guide, and he had no idea. (In case you can't tell these are two wings. The green lines indicate the extent of the two wings.)

What aircraft do these belong to?

Comment: For those who are voting to close as "Unclear". This is as clear as it can get.

Comment: @ptgflyer: Is that photo taken at the College Park Aviation Museum?

Comment: @Mike Sowsun: No, it's in one of the labs.

Comment: There is a wingless Ercoupe on display at the College Park Aviation Museum. I wonder if those wings belong to it.   http://pierregillard.zenfolio.com/img/s11/v32/p1391446624-2.jpg

Comment: The wingless Ercoupe you are talking about was my dads for 22 years. If I examined those wings, I could tell if they came from his plane. Are the wings still there? You can contact me at Lmgrips1@gmail.com or Lindsay.martin@jrmtech.com. I would be interested in acquiring these wings before they are disposed of if that is possible. Lindsay.

Comment: You would have to talk to UMD. I was just touring them.

Answer (score 114, accepted):

Those wings are from an ERCO Ercoupe. The diagonal ribs are very distinctive.

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]
[image]

Comment: Interesting: the first photo you supplied shows a wooden wing structure, whereas the remaining photos—as with the photo in the question—show metal structure; they all appear to have the same shape. Looks like the aircraft was built with wood during WWII due to aluminum shortages. Or perhaps it wasn't built during the war, but only served as a proof of concept?

Comment: Yes, they used wood in WWII.

Comment: This required super-power in identification. Standing ovation!